# Should i use content types, if i develop a solution for SP with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, content-type

I'm a little bit confused about the question.

Currently we are using site columns (which make perfectly sense for me) and content types and lists which are using that content types.
As i see it Visual Studio does not update list instances automatically when i change the underlying content type and moreover it copys data from the content type to an list-internal content type.
So as long as i will develop with VS - is there any good reason to use content types?
If i do not use them will i have disadvantages in further development?
Is there any real advantage in using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to use CT:

- easier to update/add columns in future
- assign custom CRUD forms only for specific CT
- workflows - again work with specific CT
- document library - use document templates for specific CT
- reusability
- inheritance

Think of content types as wrappers - data definition structure. I'm pretty sure when you write code you use classes and objects, CTs are the same.

It's always better to use content type even only with reference to generic type then later change whole solution just to add content type to existing content.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472236(v=office.14).aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-content-types-HA010149551.aspx

EDIT:

link to similar question:

[Are site columns and content types really worthwhile?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/are-site-columns-and-content-types-really-worthwhile)

Comment: Well my question is less, what content-types are since they define something similar like class mixed up a little bit with an interface, but my problem is the tooling. They aren't easy to update, since in VS they are copied not referenced.

Comment: There is duplication in content type definition and list (schema) definition, that's true. Unfortunately there is no way (in SP 2010) to apply changes on both places. You have to do it manually in VS. I edited my answer with link to similar topic, hope it helps.

Comment: Looking to VS it's not what i wanted to hear, but your answer is helpful :)